# How to extract sequence lines from FASTQ file?

Tags: text-processing, sed, bioinformatics

I have FASTQ formatted Illumina sequence file like this:

```
@ERR009148.2485 IL26_1382:7:1:224:616 length=36
ATCACATGCTCCTTGTTCTGCAGCTTGGTGCGGATG
+ERR009148.2485 IL26_1382:7:1:224:616 length=36
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><>><>>>5>>->><->*
@ERR009148.2486 IL26_1382:7:1:914:59 length=36
AAAGAAGTAAAATAAGAAGGCAATGCTTGTGGAAGG
+ERR009148.2486 IL26_1382:7:1:914:59 length=36
.>>74::1>174151/7152313,3&003,00&2%2
@ERR009148.2487 IL26_1382:7:1:251:589 length=36
GCCATAAACACCCCAGCACCACATTCATCAGAAGGG
+ERR009148.2487 IL26_1382:7:1:251:589 length=36
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>8>>>>>>><;<>>7
@ERR009148.2488 IL26_1382:7:1:911:194 length=36
ATTGAGGTGGAGTAGATTAGGCGTAGGTAGAAGTAG
+ERR009148.2488 IL26_1382:7:1:911:194 length=36
<>>>=>>>>>>>=;<:>>7>==<<7;=67=/57/57
```

I need to extract only the raw sequences from each record. What `sed` 
command can be used for that?

Expected output:

```
ATCACATGCTCCTTGTTCTGCAGCTTGGTGCGGATG
AAAGAAGTAAAATAAGAAGGCAATGCTTGTGGAAGG
GCCATAAACACCCCAGCACCACATTCATCAGAAGGG
ATTGAGGTGGAGTAGATTAGGCGTAGGTAGAAGTAG
```

Comment: add expected output for clarity...

Answer (score 4):

Using `sed`.

```
sed -En '/^[ATGC]+$/p' infile
```

Using `grep`:

```
grep -E '^[ATGC]+$' infile
```

Using `awk`:

```
awk '/^[ATGC]+$/' infile
```

All of these commands will return the lines that contains only set of `A, C, T, G` characters.

Answer (score 3):

You want to extract the raw sequence line from a [FASTQ formatted file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTQ_format):

Assuming no blank lines in the file, using GNU `sed`:

```
$ sed -n '2~4p' file.fastq
ATCACATGCTCCTTGTTCTGCAGCTTGGTGCGGATG
AAAGAAGTAAAATAAGAAGGCAATGCTTGTGGAAGG
GCCATAAACACCCCAGCACCACATTCATCAGAAGGG
ATTGAGGTGGAGTAGATTAGGCGTAGGTAGAAGTAG
```

The expression `2~4p` will print (`p`) every 4th line (`~4`) starting at line 2 in the input data.

If you want to be a bit more specific and get the line after each line starting with `@`:

```
$ sed -n '/^@/{n;p;}' file.fastq
```

This will locate the lines starting with the `@` character, and when one such line is found, the next line is read (`n`) and printed.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne '.put if m/^ <[ATGC]>+ $/;'  file
```

Above is an answer written in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Raku features a powerful regex engine which (some say) is more readable than what might be found in other languages.

Using the `-ne` non-autoprinting `awk`-like command line flags, an input line is read in and tested for a match against an entire line consisting of the deoxyribonucleotide letters: `A`, `T`, `G`, `C`. The line (`$_`) is out`put` if the match is found (`.put` is short for `$_.put`, to increase clarity as to which variable will be output).

Note: the programmer can demand a match to a 36-mer sequence like so:

```
~$ raku -ne '.put if m/^ <[ATGC]>**36 $/;'  file
```

Alternatively, because FASTQ format is specified as a 4-field (i.e. line) record format, you can read all `lines` in and `rotor`/`batch` them together in fours. Then just select the second line (i.e. *"Field 2 ... the raw sequence letters"*) of each, which will be zero-index `.[1]`:

```
~$ raku -e '*.[1].put for lines.rotor(4);'  file
```

---

Sample Input:

```
@ERR009148.2485 IL26_1382:7:1:224:616 length=36
ATCACATGCTCCTTGTTCTGCAGCTTGGTGCGGATG
+ERR009148.2485 IL26_1382:7:1:224:616 length=36
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><>><>>>5>>->><->*
@ERR009148.2486 IL26_1382:7:1:914:59 length=36
AAAGAAGTAAAATAAGAAGGCAATGCTTGTGGAAGG
+ERR009148.2486 IL26_1382:7:1:914:59 length=36
.>>74::1>174151/7152313,3&003,00&2%2
@ERR009148.2487 IL26_1382:7:1:251:589 length=36
GCCATAAACACCCCAGCACCACATTCATCAGAAGGG
+ERR009148.2487 IL26_1382:7:1:251:589 length=36
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>8>>>>>>><;<>>7
@ERR009148.2488 IL26_1382:7:1:911:194 length=36
ATTGAGGTGGAGTAGATTAGGCGTAGGTAGAAGTAG
+ERR009148.2488 IL26_1382:7:1:911:194 length=36
<>>>=>>>>>>>=;<:>>7>==<<7;=67=/57/57
```

Sample Output (all code examples):

```
ATCACATGCTCCTTGTTCTGCAGCTTGGTGCGGATG
AAAGAAGTAAAATAAGAAGGCAATGCTTGTGGAAGG
GCCATAAACACCCCAGCACCACATTCATCAGAAGGG
ATTGAGGTGGAGTAGATTAGGCGTAGGTAGAAGTAG
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTQ_format
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://raku.org